# Prevent a method to be executed during Unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, testing, nunit

I am trying to test a class called "PuntuadorJuego"(GameScore) which has a method “PuntuarXAcertar”(PointsIfMatching) that call a private method “Actualiza”(Update) that basically Updates the score on the Unity's interface as you can see in the code bellow, the problem is that every time I run the test it stops there. I have tried commented the line that call the method and it works but I wonder if there is any other way to prevent the method "Actualiza" to be called during testing or even better if there is a way to ignore code related to the interface while testing. Thanks.

```
[Testing class]
 public class PuntuadorTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestPuntuacionAcertar()
        {
            //Assign
            PuntuadorJuego puntuador = new PuntuadorJuego(puntuacion: 50);

            //Act
            puntuador.PuntuarXAcertar(esTurnoJ1: true);

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(expected: 60, actual: puntuador.GetPuntuacionJ1());
        }
    }


[Method called by the tested Method]
private void Actualiza(int cantidad, bool esTurnoJ1)
    {
        if (esTurnoJ1)
        {
            if (puntuacionJ1 < 0)
            {
                ValorPuntuacionText.color = Color.red;
            }
            else
            {
                ValorPuntuacionText.color = Color.white; //THIS is the error line
            }
            ValorPuntuacionText.text = puntuacionJ1 + "";
        }
        else
        {
            if (puntuacionJ2 < 0)
            {
                ValorPuntuacionJ2Text.color = Color.red;
            }
            else
            {
                ValorPuntuacionJ2Text.color = Color.white;
            }
            ValorPuntuacionJ2Text.text = puntuacionJ2 + "";
        }

        if (cantidad < 0)
        {
            burbujaPuntuacion.color = Color.red;
        }
        else 
        {
            burbujaPuntuacion.color = Color.green;
        }
        burbujaPuntuacion.text = cantidad + "";
        burbujaAnimacion.Play("Puntua");


    }


[Tested Method]
    public void PuntuarXAcertar(bool esTurnoJ1 = true) 
    {
        if (esTurnoJ1)
        {
            puntuacionJ1 += ACERTAR;
        }
        else
        {
            puntuacionJ2 += ACERTAR;
        }
        Actualiza(ACERTAR, esTurnoJ1);
    }
```

PS: I am using C#, Visual Studio and Unity.

Comment: you can use Moq to mock at least protected members. 
Also the reason why you have issues with testing here is that you have some code smells, Take a look in your code if you can separate these methods? maybe you should make your Actualiza public, make same builder class with public PuntuarXAcertar method and then you call builder from Actualiza?

Comment: Just a guess, I believe the problem is at the .Play call in the private method. Does that Play call involve any external dependency? U might need to extract the method and mock it if that’s the case

Comment: A general note/hint: You should get used to write your code in English! It is understandable that for quick and dirty projects you might prefer your native language but English is THE commonly used language. It also makes it easier for e.g. us here reading and understanding your method and variable names ;) If done right in clean code this way there should be no comments necessary to understand what you code does/is supposed to do

Comment: Most companies establish a language used for naming things in the code. Sometimes it's English, sometimes not. Of course some people may not be able to read code in another language, but telling people what language to use is kind of insensitive IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing UI calls in the code that you want to test is the source of the problem. If you are the game developer here, consider reorganizing so that `PuntuadorJuego` only determines the score but does nothing to display it. Some other code can then call both `PuntuadorJuego` and `Actualiza`.

Best way to do this is to use some architecture, which separates out the UI stuff, e.g. MVC, MVP, MVVM. I'm not familiar with Unity, but googling "Unity3d MVC", "Unity3d MVP" and "Unity3d MVVM" gave me a couple of days worth of references if I wanted to read them. :-)

BTW... MVP traditionally means Model-View-Presenter. I did find some Unity articles with MVP used in some other meaning, so take care.

Answer (score 0):

When using a Test Assembly Folder in Unity, Unity be default defines a compiler constraint named `UNITY_INCLUDE_TESTS`. You can use this with the [`#if`/`#else`/`#endif`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) preprocessor directives to include code only when running tests. For example:

```cs
public void MyMethod()
{
#if UNITY_INCLUDE_TESTS
    // Test specific code
#else
    // Production specific code
#endif
}
```

This is a very easy solution, but be very wary of using this approach since if you exclude code during testing, that code isn't being tested! Make sure you investigate why the `Actualiza` method is causing an error.

An alternative approach, already suggested is to using mocking framework, such as *Moq* or *NSubstitute*.